# Android: Disable rotations by 90°, but enable rotations by 180°

Tags: android, orientation, screen-orientation

I would like to create an Android app (for a tablet) that should be only displayed in landscape orientation, e.g. the app should ignore rotations by 90°, but support rotations by 180°.

Adding android:screenOrientation="landscape" in the manifest causes the app to ignore all rotations, (even the 180° rotations), i.e. rotating the device by 180° shows the application upside down.

Without the android:screenOrientation attribute my app is displayed "correctly" in all four positions. Rotation the device by 180° flips the UI vertically resp. horizontally.

When rotation the device the following log messages are created (maybe this helps?):

```
[...]: INFO/WindowManager(1290): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=0
Rotation is a value between 0 and 3 representing the current orientation.
```

Summarized: Is it possible to enable an app to support both landscape orientations?

Comment: I doubt it... why would you want to support upside down mode, but not other rotations?

Comment: @Mayra - the obvious thing that springs to mind is an app which doesn't suit portrait and devices which may have 'required' buttons, USB port etc on the side (which becomes the 'bottom' in a forced horizontal orientation).

Comment: @janjonas - I just spent about half an hour hacking around with this and I can't get it to work for me. Android 2.3 differentiates between normal and 'reverse' portrait and landscape orientations however, maybe you could get it to work with that when it's available for your tablet device.

Comment: getting landscape both ways is possible only on 2.3 i guess with screen oreintation set to "sensorLandscape"

Comment: @Mayra & @MisterSquonk: Yes, the reason is, that the app does not suite portrait. Due to the app's layout bases on some skyscraper graphics it needs to be displayed in landscape orientation. I know that apps should typically support both orientations, but this is kind of a special case.

Comment: @MisterSquonk & @varun: I think you are right. 2.3 introduces some new screenOrientation options like "sensorLandscape" (see http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html, section "New manifest elements and attributes"). Unfortunately, 2.3 is not available for the tablet and I do not know if it will be available in the future.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The new [sensorLandscape](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation) screen orientation is apparently meant for this purpose.

Eg, you could do:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

Unfortunately, this is only available as of Android 2.3. I'm currently looking for a way to achieve this on Froyo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. IMHO there is no way to do this in 2.2

Comment: worked for me on a 3.2.1 tablet, but not on a 4.0.2 phone (using SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT)

Comment: How can I disable the rotations by 180°?

Comment: @TharakaNirmana it's not clear what you're asking because this method won't allow the user to rotate 180 degrees. If you have set the landscape but it's inverted, you should try    `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);`