# Activity setRequestedOrientation landscape vs. reverseLandscape?

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, landscape, portrait

Is it possible to set an activity's orientation (either in the manifest or with setRequestedOrientation) and specify which landscape or portrait mode to use? I.e. can I choose the device's left or right side?

With 2.1 it doesn't seem possible, but I wondered if anyone had any workarounds?

And [where is this used](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define your Activity in the manifest you specify orientation.

```
<activity
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

will only show it in landscape.

Comment: Please re-read the question. I'm looking for a way to specify _which_ landscape mode is used.

Comment: then specify reverseLandscape instead of landscape or a combo of both. landscape|reverseLandscape.

Comment: When I set it to reverseLandscape I get an error - I suspect that value is only available in 2.3. See the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371631/android-disable-rotations-by-90-but-enable-rotations-by-180

Comment: Yeah reverse modes require API9.

Comment: Yet API 7 lets reverse mode happen when you tilt the device upside down and orientation is unspecified... seems like quite a gap to include the functionality but not the ability to set it. Ah well, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [setRequestedOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation)(8).

The [attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation) itself is from API 1, and the constant for reverseLandscape is from level 9. Without the constant it might still work? Idk, thought it might be worth a try.